# CNTK tutorial:"Hands-On Lab: Image recognition with Convolutional Networks, Batch Normalization, and Residual Nets" python problems

Tags: python, windows, cntk

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Hands-On-Labs-Image-Recognition
I am now at the point where Frank is saying:”  Please execute the following two Python scripts which you will also find in the working directory:

```
wget -rc http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
tar xvf www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
python CifarConverter.py cifar-10-batches-py
```

I am using windows 10.
I assume that wget is a Linux “thing”. I have downloaded the file from http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz 
To the path of the CifarConverter.py script as i can not run wget from cmd or cygwin.
Next I am trying to run the tar command but get an error” No such file or directory”
I changed the command to tar xvf cifar-10-python.tar.gz and executed it from Cygwin.(I just made a fresh installation of cygwin 2.6.0) This extracts the data.

Next I am running the python command:” python CifarConverter.py cifar-10-batches-py” (from cygwin)
But I am getting an error from line 48!
I have tried change the line to: print ("error") but is only getting a new error in 
import cPickle as cp
ImportError: No module named 'cPickle'

What shall i do to run the python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 3.+ version. Try it with Python 2.7, and it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to follow this tutorial using the Jupyter Noteboks found here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_201A_CIFAR-10_DataLoader.ipynb

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_201B_CIFAR-10_ImageHandsOn.ipynb

These are installed with the CNTK and is very easy to click through. Just make sure to run the CNTP34PY.BAT file to activate the Python environment first, set default directory to the Tutorials folder and start Jupyter Notebook by typing "Jupyter Notebook" from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer works, if you want to keep using Python 3, change cPickle to Pickle and it should work...

Specifically:

- Open Convert-CifarConverter.py in a text editor.
- Find and Replace cPickle with Pickle (Should be two instances.. one
  at the top where you import it, then one where it's being used in the
  code).
- Where it's being used in the code, may need to change some import
  arguments if the code still doesn't run.

For example, the encoding:

```
pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```